# How can I reorganize a sequence of DataFrames into a new one so as to swap the DataFrame index and the frame order in the sequence?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 48 monthly stock return time series dataframes (169x137) referenced by a dictionary e.g. mom[1], the first timeseries dataframe. Stocks as columns and time as rows.

I would like to create a set of new dataframes for each month where the rows are the stocks and the columns are the values in each of the above dataframes, so 169 individual (137x48) dataframes. One for each month.

I have tried the following to create the first dataframe, but not sure how to expand this to get all 48 fields:

```
date = mom[1].axes[0]
date = date[0].date()

set = mom[1].iloc[[0]].transpose()
set.columns = ['mom1']
set = set.rename_axis(date,axis=0)
set = set.rename_axis('Ticker',axis=1)
```

Comment: Pls post a sample of your dataframe and expected ouput

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `xarray` is the choice in this case. Let's create an example:

```
import xarray
import numpy as np

coords = {
    'month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul']
    , 'stock': [*'ABCDE']
    , 'frame': ['F1', 'F2', 'F3']}
dims = ['month', 'stock', 'frame']
shape = [len(v) for v in coords.values()]
data = np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)

df = xarray.DataArray(data, coords, dims)
```

We can reach any subframe with `loc`:

```
>>> print(df.loc['Jan'].to_pandas())

frame  F1  F2  F3
stock            
A       0   1   2
B       3   4   5
C       6   7   8
D       9  10  11
E      12  13  14

>>> print(df.loc[:, :, 'F1'].to_pandas())

stock   A   B   C   D    E
month                     
Jan     0   3   6   9   12
Feb    15  18  21  24   27
Mar    30  33  36  39   42
Apr    45  48  51  54   57
May    60  63  66  69   72
Jun    75  78  81  84   87
Jul    90  93  96  99  102
```

We can generate a dictionary of data frames as well:

```
month_stock = {f: df.loc[..., f].to_pandas() for f in coords['frame']}
stock_frame = {m: df.loc[m].to_pandas() for m in coords['month']}
```

If we have a list of data frames at the beginning, then we can generate `DataArray` from it. For example:

```
# create some initial dummy list of data frames
mom = [*month_stock.values()]

# get sample dataframe to extract index and columns
sample = mom[0]

# keep the order of dimensions (frame, index, column) in coords
# so we can pass mom as data to xarray.DataArray
# and then we reorder dims with transpose
coords = {
    'frame': [f'mom{i}' for i in range(len(mom))]
    , sample.index.name: sample.index.values
    , sample.columns.name: sample.columns.values
}

da = xarray.DataArray(mom, coords).transpose(
    sample.index.name,
    sample.columns.name,
    'frame'
)
```

Now we can generate a new sequence of data frames as we did above, sort of:

```
rearanged_data = {x: da.loc[x].to_pandas() for x in sample.index}
```

With a dictionary of data frames we can do almost the same:

```
mom = month_stock

sample = next(iter(mom.values()))

coords = {
    'frame': [*mom.keys()]
    , sample.index.name: sample.index.values
    , sample.columns.name: sample.columns.values
}

da = xarray.DataArray([*mom.values()], coords).transpose(
    sample.index.name,
    sample.columns.name,
    'frame'
)
```

See also: [Quick overview of xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/getting-started-guide/quick-overview.html)